# TYPO3 Symfony Services.yaml class not find

Tags: symfony, typo3

I am trying to update an older extension to Typo3 V11.
Currently I am getting the following error:

[image]

Here my Services.yaml file:

```
# Configuration/Services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
     public: false

 HGA\Simpleblog\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'
    exclude: '../Classes/Domain/Model/*'

  HGA\Simpleblog\Utilities\SqlUtil:
    public: true
```

And here the beginnig of the BlogsController.php file:

```
<?php
namespace HGA\Simpleblog\Controller;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Http\ForwardResponse;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment as Environment;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use HGA\Simpleblog\Utilities;
use HGA\Simpleblog\Utilities\SqlUtil;
use HGA\Simpleblog\Domain\Model;
use HGA\Simpleblog\Domain\Repository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject;

/***
 *
 * This file is part of the "SimpleBlog" Extension for TYPO3 CMS.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
*
 ***/
/**
 * BlogsController
 */
class BlogsController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{

    /**
    * @var SqlUtil $sqlUtil
    */
    protected $sqlUtil;

    public function __construct(SqlUtil $sqlUtil)
    {
      $this->sqlUtil = $sqlUtil;
    }
```

In my opinion, the class BlogsController is included inside the mentioned file.
The extension was working with an older version of Typo3. But I had to add the `Services.yaml` file.

I am not using composer!
TYPO3 V11.5.8.

Any idea, what could be the problem?

**EDIT**

After a while, the problem disappeared! What I did in between, I had to update the Windows Server 2019 operation system.

Answer (score 0):

Is the filename really `BlogController.php`? Shouldn't it rather be `BlogsController.php`?

Comment: Georg, thank you. It was an typing error. The file name is `BlogsController`. I have already edit it,

Comment: I don't know, who gave my original question and Georgs answer a negative rating, but he has read it in the right way!!! Because the typing error was only in my question above (which I have corrected) and not in TYPO3 code. `So the real problem still exist!!!`

Comment: Are you using composer?  If yes, is the autoload section correct in the extension. if not using composer, Install Tool > Rebuild PHP Autoload Information > rebuild

and the file is really in typo3conf/ext/simpleblog/Classes/Controller/BlogsController.php?

I find it a bit strange that in the filepath the last slash is a \ instead of a /, maybe this is another hint for you

 

I am not using windows but if you go for it I suggest wsl2